# when i was creating out of tree module for gnu radio , after the command " make test" i got the following error

Tags: gnuradio

I was trying to create an out-of-tree module `square_ff` for GNU Radio following the steps as given in [OutOfTreeModules](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/OutOfTreeModules).

After the command `make test` I got an error. I typed `ctest -V` and got the following result. I am new in this.

```
manash@manash-Studio-1435:~/gr-howto/build$ ctest -V
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/manash/gr-howto/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :/home/manash/gr-howto/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project /home/manash/gr-howto/build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 1
    Start 1: test_howto

1: Test command: /bin/sh "/home/manash/gr-howto/build/lib/test_howto_test.sh"
1: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
1: 
1: 
1/2 Test #1: test_howto .......................   Passed    0.00 sec
test 2
    Start 2: qa_square_ff

2: Test command: /bin/sh "/home/manash/gr-howto/build/python/qa_square_ff_test.sh"
2: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
2: Traceback (most recent call last):
2:   File "/home/manash/gr-howto/python/qa_square_ff.py", line 22, in <module>
2:     import howto_swig as howto
2:   File "/home/manash/gr-howto/build/swig/howto_swig.py", line 416, in <module>
2:     square_ff = square_ff.make;
2: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'make'
2/2 Test #2: qa_square_ff .....................***Failed    0.38 sec

50% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =   0.38 sec
..
```

Answer (score 0):

The test is telling you that there was no 'make' factory function found for your 'square_ff'. Did you implement your code using the private implementation used throughout GNUradio, and create a square_ff::make() factory constructor?

If you aren't sure, look at other modules in GNURadio or the Ettus Research UHD software, and post your own code.